# Tkinter entry widget 'show' option

Tags: python, tkinter

I am coding a tkinter program whereby a user can login. I want my entry box for the password to be able to show 'Password' and then when a user starts typing I want to use the 'show' option to make it so the characters are hidden. The issue is 'show' does not update like for example the textvariable option. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: It would be great if you could *'show'* us some code and maybe an image describing your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I just figured it out, I can use entry.config(show="*") to change the state of the option while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
show="\u2022"
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem
you need to bind both Enter And Leave to your entries and use config on your entry  for changing show into empty string like this :

```
en1.config(show="")
```

it will show you the exact text and then again change it to "*"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).